# False proof: no element has a prime norm in the ring $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading *Fermat's Last Theorem* by Harold M. Edwards. In the ring $\mathbb Z[\zeta_p]$, with $\zeta_p$ a primitive $p$-th root of unity ($p$ prime), we have the norm $Nf(\zeta_p)$ of an element $f(\zeta_p)$, equal to the product of all conjugates of $f(\zeta_p)$. The norm is a positive integer and is multiplicative - $(Nf)(Ng)=N(fg)$.

How can any element of this ring have prime norm? Suppose $a$ has prime norm $Na$. Thus we have a factorization:

$$Na=a\cdot a'\cdot a''...$$

Where $a, a', a''...$ are the conjugates of $a$. Clearly $Na=Na'=Na''$ and so on, and $N(Na)=Na$ because the norm of an ordinary integer is the integer itself. But then

$$Na=(Na)^{p-1}$$

Which is impossible if $Na$ is prime. In fact we've "shown" that all elements of this ring have norms that are $(p-1)$-th powers.

Comment: By the way: $N(1-\zeta_p)=p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The norm of an ordinary integer is the integer itself" -- this is the flaw in your reasoning. The norm of an ordinary integer is the integer to the power of the size of the field extension, in this case $p - 1$.

The problem is that you are taking norm to mean "product of the Galois conjugates" which is only right if the element you are taking the norm of actually generates the field extension in question.

Comment: Usually we put this explicitly in the notaiton, to avoid precisely this confusion: $N_{F/\mathbb{Q}}$ where $F$ is the field over which we are working.